# Efficient Exponentiation For HUGE Numbers (I'm Talking Googols)

Tags: c++, biginteger, bignum, exponentiation

I am in the midst of solving a simple combination problem whose solution is 2^(n-1).

The only problem is 1 <= n <= 2^31 -1 (max value for signed 32 bit integer)

I tried using Java's BigInteger class but It times out for numbers 2^31/10^4 and greater, so that clearly doesn't work out.

Furthermore, I am limited to using only built-in classes for Java or C++.

Knowing I require speed, I chose to build a class in C++ which does arithmetic on strings.

Now, when I do multiplication, my program multiplies similarly to how we multiply on paper for efficiency (as opposed to repeatedly adding the strings).

But even with that in place, I can't multiply 2 by itself 2^31 - 1 times, it is just not efficient enough.

So I started reading texts on the problem and I came to the solution of...

`2^n = 2^(n/2) * 2^(n/2) * 2^(n%2)` (where / denotes integer division and % denotes modulus)

This means I can solve exponentiation in a logarithmic number of multiplications. But to me, I can't get around how to apply this method to my code? How do I choose a lower bound and what is the most efficient way to keep track of the various numbers that I need for my final multiplication?

If anyone has any knowledge on how to solve this problem, please elaborate (example code is appreciated).

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone for all your help! Clearly this problem is meant to be solved in a realistic way, but I did manage to outperform `java.math.BigInteger` with a power function that only performs ceil(log2(n)) iterations.

If anyone is interested in the code I've produced, here it is...

```
using namespace std;

bool m_greater_or_equal (string & a, string & b){ //is a greater than or equal to b?
    if (a.length()!=b.length()){
        return a.length()>b.length();
    }
    for (int i = 0;i<a.length();i++){
        if (a[i]!=b[i]){
            return a[i]>b[i];
        }
    }
    return true;
}

string add (string& a, string& b){
    if (!m_greater_or_equal(a,b)) return add(b,a);
    string x = string(a.rbegin(),a.rend());
    string y = string(b.rbegin(),b.rend());
    string result = "";
for (int i = 0;i<x.length()-y.length()+1;i++){
    y.push_back('0');
}

int carry = 0;
for (int i =0;i<x.length();i++){
    char c = x[i]+y[i]+carry-'0'-'0';
    carry = c/10;
    c%=10;
    result.push_back(c+'0');
}
if (carry==1) result.push_back('1');
return string(result.rbegin(),result.rend());

}

string multiply (string&a, string&b){
    string row = b, tmp;
    string result = "0";

    for (int i = a.length()-1;i>=0;i--){

        for (int j= 0;j<(a[i]-'0');j++){
            tmp = add(result,row);
            result = tmp;
        }
        row.push_back('0');
    }
    return result;
}

int counter = 0;

string m_pow (string&a, int exp){
    counter++;
    if(exp==1){
        return a;
    }
    if (exp==0){
        return "1";
    }
    string p = m_pow(a,exp/2);
    string res;
    if (exp%2==0){
        res = "1";  //a^exp%2 is a^0 = 1
    } else {
        res = a;   //a^exp%2 is a^1 = a
    }
    string x = multiply(p,p);
    return multiply(x,res);
    //return multiply(multiply(p,p),res); Doesn't work because multiply(p,p) is not const

}

int main(){


    string x ="2";

    cout<<m_pow(x,5000)<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<counter<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no "built-in" big-number classes in C++. Do you still want to consider popular libraries, or do you want to scrap C++ from the question? I don't think anyone will guide you through creating your own bignum library here when excellent libraries already exist (GMP).

Comment: "Knowing I require speed, I chose to build a class in C++ which does arithmetic on strings."

Assuming you mean the same think I do when talking about strings (that is something build of chars) that really won't help your performance much (generally take the biggest possible type as a base). Besides do I understand you correctly that you need numbers in the order of 2^(2^31)? In that case you really require all the speed you can get, so I'd advise against writing such a class yourself.

Comment: If you want the answer in binary, then you don't have to do any computation (just write 1 followed by `n - 1` zeros - as mentioned in Oli's answer). But if you want to print the answer in decimal... well... Don't count on Java's BigInteger to do it... And if you're talking sizes significantly larger than `n > 2^32`, don't count on GMP to do it either... You'll run out of memory before that happens...

Comment: Yeh, I just didn't think of bit arithmetic, that would probably be the best way to go, although the recursive approach that dasblinkenlight brings to the table is also quite interesting and I will try it out as well.

Comment: Just a note on using std::string: if you'd use std::vector<unsigned long> for the representation (with an extra bit to indicate the sign) and made sure to use unsigned long long for computations you should be able to improve performance further while essentially using the same approach.

Comment: @Dietmar I doubt that would improve performance as I only keep 1 digit at each index. If I kept 1 digit numbers in unsigned long, that would be a memory waste because sizeof(char) = 1 while sizeof(long) = 8

Comment: @JimmyHuch: well, right. However, if you'd work with hands with more finger, e.g. with 1000000000 fingers, your approach stays valid and you can still format the number reasonably simple.

Comment: @JimmyHuch You should investigate your algorithms, `2^20 = 1048576 ? 1040576` is the first power of 2 your code returns wrong results for, but from then on, it's wrong at least to 32 (didn't check further).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to apply this method in your code is to apply it the most direct way - recursively. It works for any number `a`, not only for `2`, so I wrote code that takes `a` as a parameter to make it more interesting:

```
MyBigInt pow(MyBigInt a, int p) {
    if (!p) return MyBigInt.One;
    MyBigInt halfPower = pow(a, p/2);
    MyBigInt res = (p%2 == 0) ? MyBigInt.One : a;
    return res * halfPower * halfPower;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it'll recurse infinitely.

Comment: @kerreksb Oops, you are right! I missed the base case (fixed now). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @Oli's answer, this is not a question of computing `2^n` as that's trivially just a `1` followed by `0`s in binary.

But since you want to print them out in decimal, this becomes a question of how to convert from binary to decimal for very large numbers.

**My answer to that is that it's not realistic.** (I hope this question just stems from curiosity.)

You mention trying to compute `2^(2^31 - 1)` and printing that out in decimal. That number is **646,456,993 digits long**.

- Java **BigInteger** can't do it. It's meant for small numbers and uses `O(n^2)` algorithms.
- As mentioned in the comments, there are no built-in BigNum libraries in C++.
- Even **Mathematica** can't handle it:  `General::ovfl : Overflow occurred in computation.`
- Your best bet is to use the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) library.

---

**If you're just interested in seeing part of the answer:**

```
2^(2^31 - 1) = 2^2147483647 = 

880806525841981676603746574895920 ... 7925005662562914027527972323328

(total: 646,456,993 digits)
```

This was done using a close-sourced library and took roughly 37 seconds and 3.2 GB of memory on a Core i7 2600K @ 4.4 GHz including the time needed to write all 646 million digits to a massive text file.
(It took notepad longer to open the file than needed to compute it.)

---

Now to answer your question of how to actually compute such a power in the general case, @dasblinkenlight has the answer to that which is a variant of [Exponentiation by Squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Converting from binary to decimal for large numbers is a much harder task. The standard algorithm here is [Divide-and-Conquer conversion](http://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html#Binary-to-Radix).

I do not recommend you try to implement the latter - as it's far beyond the scope of starting programmers. (and is also somewhat math-intensive)

Comment: The algorithm posted by dasblinkenlight is one variant of exponentiation by squaring, that sentence is not well worded.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the `halfPower * halfPower` in his answer. Updating...

Comment: @Mysticial : i just wrote 2 `awk` functions extremely tailored to `2^n-1` exponents, one iterative, one recursive, ENTIRELY without using modulo, division, string ops or bit-wise ops, that leverages `GMP` only to the degree of a squaring call, and benchmarked it against the built-in operator, and was nearly zero speed reduction. For something like `3 ^ ( 2^21 - 1 )`, i.e. `3 ^ 2097151`, the times were like `2.624 secs` for built-in operator, `2.592 secs` for iterative, and ` 2.643 secs` for recursive - which are kinda surreal considering `awk` doesn't use `JIT` compilation techniques. …...

Comment: ……. for powers of 2, my `gawk / GMP` couldn't do anything `>= 2^30` for the exponent, but the timing for `2  ^ ( 2 ^ 29 - 1 )` `:=` `2 ^ 536,870,911`, was `2.352 secs`. like others said, `2^(n-1)` is identical to `1 << (n-1)`, so I just do the ultra lazy exponent tracking of `29…. 28… 27…` …. which brings me to my point - I'm really confused why the algo insists on dividing, taking modulos, bit-masking the `LSB`, or bit-shift AT ALL to do exponentiation via binary squaring.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do any multiplication at all.  2^(n-1) is just `1 << (n-1)`, i.e. 1 followed by `(n-1)` zeros (in binary).

Comment: Still no way to store 1 << 2147483647 in even a 128-bit integer

Comment: Aww, I see, have the number stored in a string of binary digits and then convert it into decimal, that might just work!

Comment: @JimmyHuch: Yes, of course, you will need to think of a suitable way to store this number.  But that's not the question you asked!

Comment: No worries, I think I can figure it out.

Comment: Okay, I need to express the answer in decimal, so the conversion represents a problem because it still requires me to do the arithmetic 2^(n-1) to apply conversion, which leads back to the main problem. This won't work unless there is a more efficient way to convert binary to decimal (which I doubt there is).

Comment: @Jimmy: You want to display a number with 2^31 binary digits?  (this is approximately 670 million decimal digits.)

Comment: Which is why I've got to use decimal ;)

Comment: @JimmyHuch: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: 1 << 2147483647 - numbers don't even go that high.

Comment: If you just want the answer: `2^2147483647 = 88080652584198167660374 ... 14027527972323328` (It's 646,456,993 digits long.)

Comment: I need to do this to master the art of programming

Comment: @Jimmy, note that a 32 bit process doesnt have enough memory to hold those values as chars of binary digits.  You'll have to use _actual_ binary.  Chars of decimal digits is over half a gigabyte of data.